# Scala split function error

Tags: scala

Can you please correct my code.I am trying to print x22 by spliting x11.

```
object ScalaString {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var x =" Hello world"
    x.filter(_!='l').foreach(println)
    //for(c <- x) println(c)
   println(x.stripPrefix(" ").drop(2).take(2).capitalize)
    **var x11=" hello|world|india"
    var x22=( x11.split("|").map(_.trim()))
    println(x22.toString())**

  }

}

output:
w
o
r
d
Ll
**[Ljava.lang.String;@56431753**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what the `toString` of an `Array` looks like. Try `x22.mkString` instead.

Comment: Hello Boss,Thats worked perfectly. Please let me know what the difference.. Why it was showing the memory address.

Comment: The difference is... it's a different function. `Array` functions in general are optimized for performance rather than anything else; in general e.g. `Vector` is similar but more user-friendly, and has a `toString` that returns something more sensible. `split` returns an `Array` because that's the `java.lang.String` API.